# I'm trying to deploy Node.js app to Google Cloud Platform but catching error with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, keystonejs

I've created a Node.js app and now I need to deploy it to Google Cloud Compute Engine. As it was shown in the guide I created new project in GSP, then I downloaded GSP SDK and created app.yaml with following code:

```
#[START app.yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Then I ran `gcloud app deploy` and got following error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
message: 
 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' 
Error: KeystoneJS (seebelarus.by) failed to start - Check that you are running 'mongod' in a separate process.
```

So, what do I need to do, to fix this error?

Comment: Start by editing your question and include code, configuration and deployment files. Also, where is your MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is saying it is trying to connect to Mongo locally. Was there a step in your tutorial perhaps for setting up a Mongo server?

My guess is that you need to create a Mongo server, and update the connection string to reference that one's location, as opposed to localhost.